# Websocket related errors when working with Django Rest Framework and Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2, django-rest-framework

I'm working with Django 2, Django Rest Framework, Vue and Docker on a rather simple CRUD SPA.

The basic CRUD functions are already working properly, but I'm constantly getting a long list of errors in the browsers developer console.

These are the errors:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/sockjs-node/960/pxv3l3z5/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

`POST http://localhost:8000/sockjs-node/960/mf1pj0yr/xhr_streaming?t=1558372142795 403 (Forbidden)`

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/sockjs-node/124/3qg4rd5f/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

They all seem to be related with a web socket issue, but I'm not actively using websockets. The app just issues a couple of requests to the Django Rest Framework backend.

So I really don't know what is causing these errors. Maybe I configured something wrong?

Comment: Do you have both `runserver` and the JS application running on the same port?